# ¿En javaScript se puede definir el nombre de un objeto de un array de objetos de forma dinamica?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Quiero saber si en javascript se puede definir el nombre de un objeto de forma dinamica.

ejemplo:

```
variableDinamica = [accion1, accion2]; //ejemplo de array
acciones = {
    variableDinamica: {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    
}
```

/////////html/////////////77

```
    acciones = {
            accion1: {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            accion2: {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            
   }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más específico con qué te refieres a *"definar el nombre de un objeto de forma dinámica"*? ¿Y cómo eso está relacionado al ejemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se puede, pero tendras que seguir un paso mas para poder hacerlo, ya que no se puede de manera directa, recordemos que las `propiedades` de un objeto se pueden definir de dos formas:

Con un punto:

```
objeto.propiedad = x;
```

Con corchetes y comillas:

```
objeto["propiedad"] = x;
```

Ambos dan como resultado un objeto de este estilo:

```
{
   "propiedad": el valor que contenga la variable x
}
```

Asi que supongamos que tu ya tienes listo un arreglo con los nombres de las propiedades con las cuales quieres construir el objeto, entonces lo que tendrias que hacer es iterarlo primero, e irle añadiendo estas propiedades en base a tu array:

```js
const accion1 = "pasear";
const accion2 = "nadar";

//No es recomendable dejar las variables sin declaracion NO LO HAGAS
//Te recomiendo que le pongas let o const segun lo necesites.
variableDinamica = [accion1, accion2]; //ejemplo de array

//De nuevo inciso importante NO DEJES VARIABLES SIN DECLARACION.
acciones = {};
variableDinamica.map(el => acciones[el] = {type: "boolean"});

console.log(acciones);
```

Comment: Nota: el metodo `map` hace parte de los arrays, en este caso lo uso como un iterador mas corto un poco mas avanzado, pero esto puede realizarse de manera basica con cualquier tipo de ciclo y el resultado seria el mismo, sea `for`, `while`, `do while` etc. el punto es iterar el array. `map` en este caso nos sirve de manera perfecta para ello.